# What is transpose of the product $(A \cdot B \cdot C \cdot D)^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra

What is transpose of the product $(A \cdot B \cdot C \cdot D)^{T}$ ?

I know the transpose formula $(A \cdot B)^{T} = B^{T}\cdot A^{T}$ , but what if I have more matrices in the brackets?

Comment: Don't you mean the transpose of the product $ABCD$?

Answer (score 2):

We can apply associativity and distributivity one operation at a time:
$$\begin{aligned}(A \cdot B \cdot C \cdot D)^{T}
&=(((A \cdot B) \cdot C) \cdot D)^{T}\\
&=D^T\cdot ((A \cdot B) \cdot C)^{T}\\
&=D^T\cdot C^T \cdot (A \cdot B)^{T}\\
&=D^T\cdot C^T \cdot B^T \cdot A^{T}
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 1):

$A \cdot B$ is itself a matrix. Same for $C \cdot D$. So:

$$(A \cdot B \cdot C \cdot D)^{T} = ((A \cdot B) \cdot (C \cdot D))^{T} = (C \cdot D)^{T}\cdot(A \cdot B)^T = D^T \cdot C^T \cdot B^T \cdot A^T$$

Comment: But if I have $(A\cdot B\cdot C\cdot D\cdot E)^{T}$ , should I  rather  apply associativity and distributivity?

Comment: It already *is* using Associativity. It is because of associativity that you can break this up any way you want. For example: $(A \cdot B \cdot C \cdot D \cdot E)^{T} = ((A \cdot B) \cdot (C \cdot D \cdot E))^{T} = (C \cdot D \cdot E)^{T}\cdot(A \cdot B)^T = (C \cdot (D \cdot E))^{T}\cdot(A \cdot B)^T= (D\cdot E)^T \cdot C^T  \cdot B^T \cdot A^T = E^T\cdot D^T \cdot C^T  \cdot B^T \cdot A^T$. And I am not sure what you mean by Distributivity in this context ...